# $p^k$-cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime integer. Let $\Phi_p(X):=X^{p-1}+X^{p-2}+\ldots+X+1$ and for any positive integer $k$ let $\Phi_{p^k}(X):=\Phi_p(X^{p^{k-1}})$.

I'm asked to show that every coefficient (but the leading one) in $\Phi_{p^k}(X+1)$ is divisible by $p$.

This is what i did, that show that the claim is false: by definition we have
\begin{align}
\Phi_{p^k}(X+1)&=\Phi_p\left( (X+1)^{p^{k-1}}\right)\\
&=(X+1)^{(p-1)p^{k-1}}+\ldots +(X+1)^{p^{k-1}}\\
&=(X+1)^{p^{k-1}}\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}(X+1)^j
\end{align}
It is easy to prove that, modulo $p$, we have the following relation:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}(X+1)^j=X^{p-1}$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\Phi_{p^k}(X+1)&=(X+1)^{p^{k-1}}X^{p-1}\\
&=(X^{p^{k-1}}+1)X^{p-1}\\
&=X^{(p-1)p^{k-1}}+X^{p-1}
\end{align}
which has a coefficient $1$ of degree $p-1$, not divisible by $p$.

Who is wrong? Me or the author of this exercise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the last step of the first three line calculation. You seem to think that
$$
(X+1)^{jp^{k-1}}=(X+1)^{p^{k-1}}(X+1)^j,$$
but this is false. Instead you have
$$(X+1)^{jp^{k-1}}=\left((X+1)^{p^{k-1}}\right)^j.$$

A better idea would be to use the "freshman's dream"
$$
(X+1)^{p^{k-1}}\equiv X^{p^{k-1}}+1\pmod p.
$$
Together with the above correction this reduces your task to the familiar case $k=1$, but in the variable $X^{p^{k-1}}$ instead of $X$. Can you complete the exercise with these hints?